# Putting directional antennae on 2602e, one on the A port, one on the B port and one on the C port to cover 3 different aisles

Tags: wireless

on setting up the access point I have put one directional antenna on the 2602e A port to go down on aisle, one on B to go down another, and finally one on C to go down a third aisle.  Is this a bad set up?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

> on setting up the access point I have put one directional antenna on the 2602e A port to go down on aisle, one on B to go down another, and finally one on C to go down a third aisle. Is this a bad set up?

Not only bad, completely broken. Not only won't you get any sort of advanced benefits (such as diversity/multipath, beam forming, etc), you will get signal that isn't even usable by the clients.

This 802.11n AP uses the antennas for separate spatial streams. Specifically, antenna #1 is used for spatial stream #1, antenna #2 for spatial stream #2, and so on.

So in your first aisle, clients will be able to connect at MCS values 0-7 (maximum 150Mbps with 40Mhz wide channels and short GI).

In aisle two, clients won't get any usable signal because it would need at least MCS values 8-15 for the second spatial stream (i.e. single SS clients would be able to work to begin with). However those clients wouldn't have access to the first spatial stream, so they will not actually receive data correctly (since it is split across both spatial streams).

In the third aisle, the same issue is compounded, with clients only being able to access the third spatial stream. Two spatial stream clients won't be able to communicate at all and three spatial stream clients won't actually receive data as it is split across three spatial streams and they only receive the third.

Answer (score 3):

Utterly bad. This ruins antenna diversity and beam forming capabilities, essentially crippling the AP.